# How to backup android the calendar file?

Tags: android, calendar, backup

Does anybody know, which files I need to save in order to have a simple backup?
Reason for my question is, that my Galaxy Android smartphone lost all calendar data without any interaction.
I found tons of apps, tons of sync stuff, but NO simple list of files to save.
I do NOT want to save my data remote on Google.

Comment: OT not a programming question. Go on http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this too, this is the best I could find:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.calendars.pimlical/21657

Also, ended up using this app to save a few calendars.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25210/how-to-backup-the-android-calendar-file-is-there-such-a-file